# Libre Office: See the dictionary words?

Tags: libreoffice, dictionary

I'm interested in browsing and seeing the complete list of words that make up the dictionary that is used to spelling-check and other similar language tasks in Libre office 4.3.3.2 , the english USA dictionary.

Research:
I followed carefully [this instructions](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Removing_Words_From_a_User-Defined_Dictionary): (step 1 and 2) and they got me to a dialog in wich I can edit list of words I myself added... but not the "built in" words. For example I added "boludo", a word in spanish, and that's the only word I see, I can remove it and I can add new ones, but I can't see the built in words or remove them.

I also followed [this link](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/american-british-canadian-spelling-hyphen-thesaurus-dictionaries/releases/3.0/kpp-american-english-dictionary-797865-words-list.oxt/view) but it downloads  a installer of the extension for Libre office.

Comment: What research/web searching have you done so far towards trying to figure this out?

Comment: @tniles09 I did search on google: "dictionary english libreoffice" and ended [here](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/american-british-canadian-spelling-hyphen-thesaurus-dictionaries/releases/3.0/kpp-american-english-dictionary-797865-words-list.oxt/view) and it didn't help me because it was for installing an extension. Now I'm researching a little more with Libre office, following some instructions on [this similar problem](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Removing_Words_From_a_User-Defined_Dictionary)

Comment: @tniles09 see my new post

Comment: @ Santropedro see my new answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can find online, open/libreoffice uses [Hunspell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunspell) which is compatible with (derived from) myspell. You can find system-level installed dictionaries in

- `/usr/share/hunspell`
- `/usr/share/myspell`
- `/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/wordbook` (I would start here)

Here's a related post from [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72099/how-to-install-a-libreoffice-dictionary-spelling-check-thesaurus) on how to install additional dictionaries, providing some additional insight on the subject.

You can also get the [source files here](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/pre-releases#Source_code). Look under `libreoffice/dictionaries`.

Comment: Yes!!!!! You rock!!!! I will accept now because it seems very promising, but I don't know if my spanish extension added dictionary will be (but probably it is!)